# Storing ssrs reports in a file that can be called immediately

Tags: caching, ssrs-2008

Hi Fellow SSRS Developers,

I have a scenario that I'm trying to tend to but need to know if what I want to do is even possible.

I have 4 reports that I would like to have run and then store the actual report in a file on a server. The reason for this need is because the response time on the reports is a bit long and I've done everything in SQL to speed it up.

What I want to have happen, is when a user clicks on the report name, instead of rendering the report on their screen I simply want to call the report that is already in a file so that it will load in lightning quick time.

Has anyone ever done this with SSRS and is it even possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Other than running reports on demand, there are two specific options: Running from a Cached report and running from a Snapshot.

You can see details on all of this in [Setting Report Processing Properties](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159241%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

**Caching**

From Books Online:

> To enhance performance, you can specify a report (and data) to be
>   cached temporarily when a user runs the report. The cached copy is
>   subsequently available to other users who access the same report. With
>   this approach, if ten users open the report, only the first request
>   results in report processing. The report is subsequently cached, and
>   the remaining nine users view the cached report.

So here you can see that it is a specific user action that causes a stored report to be created.

See [Report Caching in Reporting Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155927%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

**Snapshots**

From Books Online:

> A report snapshot is a report that contains layout information and
>   data that is retrieved at a specific point in time. You can run a
>   report as a report snapshot to prevent the report from being run at
>   arbitrary times (for example, during a scheduled backup). A report
>   snapshot is usually created and subsequently refreshed on a schedule,
>   allowing you to time exactly when report and data processing will
>   occur. If a report is based on queries that take a long time to run,
>   or on queries that use data from a data source that you prefer no one
>   access during certain hours, you should run the report as a snapshot.

Here you can see that these are these are generally set up on a regular schedule, i.e. independent of user activity.

See [Creating, Modifying, and Deleting Snapshots in Report History](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156325%28v=sql.100%29.aspx).

In this case it seems like **Snapshots** might be your best option so you have more control of when the stored report is created. The main issue with Snapshots is that they need either stored credentials or an unattended execution account so might not be possible in all cases.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for all the tips. I will try each one out and see where I come, but I finally have a starting point with more than one option available. I am going to give this a shot right now and see what snags, if any, I experience.